# Как правильно изменить размер раздела в Ubuntu через gparted?

Tags: ubuntu

Доброго времени суток! Возникла проблема - не хватает места в разделе `/dev/std5`, как через gparted взять свободное место с `/dev/sda7`? Просто команда Изменить/Переместить не дает этого сделать (попросту ползунок невозможно переместить), отмонтировать `/dev/sda7` тоже не получается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Загрузитесь с любого LiveCD с линуксом и проделайте нужную операцию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А напрямую нельзя, получается, с уже установленным gparted?

Comment: @ЮрийОстроух это будет труднее - придется поломать fstab, чтобы /home не монтировался, без опыта лучше так не делать.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую через LiveCD