# Форматирование разделов диска Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

У меня есть несколько разделов [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тот, который на dev/sda5 я хочу увеличить. Есть свободное место перед этим разделом. Как добавить это свободное место на dev/sda5? Программа этого сделать не дает: увеличить размер раздела за счет раздела который выше нельзя, и перемещать разделы тоже не получается.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/minitool-partition-wizard/?platform=linux

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно изменить размер раздела в Ubuntu через gparted?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526196/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-ubuntu-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-gparted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что вы хотите менять разделы на диске, с которого запущен Linux. Этого делать нельзя. Ключик возле имени раздела намекает на то, что раздел заблокирован.

Кроме того, вы, кажется, собираетесь увеличивать ваш раздел за счет раздела с  Windows. Нежелательно оставлять Windows в тесноте на разделе.
Если вы собираетесь им пользоваться, то надо хорошо подумать, сколько он еще может вырасти. Постирать все ненужное, временные файлы и мусор. В любом случае предпочтительно **уменьшить раздел (диск) Windows из самого Windows**. Он сам скажет, какой минимальный раздел ему нужен, учитывая свои скрытые файлы. Про себя могу сказать, что после установки Ubuntu на «попробовать», Windows у меня запускался только ради старинной программы, которая не работала под Wine.

Для того, чтобы поменять что-то на диске, вам нужно:

- Заранее неплохо бы сделать бэкап, если там есть что-то важное.
- Убедиться, что батарейки хватит надолго. Передвижение раздела может занять несколько часов, и вы не хотите, чтоб оно прервалось раньше времени. Лучше всего включить компьютер в сеть на время работы Gparted.
- Поднять Ubuntu с флешки.
- Отмонтировать раздел, который вы собираетесь менять, например, командой

  umount /dev/sda5
  (возможно, это можно сделать и из самой Gparted, точно не помню)
- Запустить Gparted и увеличить ваш раздел.

Удачи!